# PHP DateInterval missing a period

Tags: php, time, dateinterval

My aim is to generate a timestamp of every minute between two given dates (the actual problem is different, but this is similar in structure and simpler to describe). I'm using the following code:

```
    $Interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 minute');
    $Period = new DatePeriod('2013-01-01', $Interval, '2014-01-01');

    foreach ($Period as $Dt){
       echo "Minute" . $Dt->format('i');
    }
```

Problem is when I run this, I would expect to find 365*24*60 entries, or 525,600, but instead only 525,540 are returned. Interestingly, a whole 60 minute period is missing in March (13th March, 2-3am is missing).

This is really weird.. am I missing something completely obvious? Using PHP version 5.4.16

Cheers,
Adrian

Comment: I wonder if that could have anything to do with daylight savings perhaps? Now try running it again for the clock change dates in October.... that's why DateTime objects are better than the basic PHP time functions, because they are timezone and daylight savings aware

Comment: You haven't set a time zone so it'll be using the default time zone configured in PHP. If March 13 was not when you switched to summer time, that's the explanation.

Comment: Mark Baker, you sir are a genius. I cannot thank you enough! ;)