# Function with DatePeriod iteration is missing one day on second function call

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I have a codeigniter function with following function:

```
/**
 * Returns Days within a period of time defined by two DateTime objects
 *
 *
 * @param $start DateTime
 * @param $end DateTime
 * @param $points
 *
 * $return['days'][x]
 */
public function getDaysInRange(DateTime $start,DateTime $end){
    $this->debug(memory_get_usage()/1024,"Memory Usage in KB");
    $this->debug(memory_get_peak_usage()/1024,"Peak Memory Usage in KB");
    $this->debug(memory_get_peak_usage(true)/1024,"Real Peak Memory Usage in KB");

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1Day Interval
    $startC= clone $start;
    $startC->setTime(0,0,0);
    $endC = clone $end;
    $endC->setTime(0,0,0);
    // Workaround because last day of period is not in Iterator
    $endC->add($interval);

    $this->debug($startC,"Get Days in Range Start");
    $this->debug($endC,"Get Days in Range End");

    $daterange = new DatePeriod($startC, $interval,$endC);

    $return = array('days' => array());
    foreach($daterange as $date){
        $this->debug($date->format("Y-m-d"),"Single Day in Daterange");
        $return['days'][] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
    }

    $this->debug($return,"Return of getDays in Range");
    return $return;
}
```

When I call this function 2 x times with different DateTime objects.

```
             [start] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2014-03-01 00:00:00
                            [timezone_type] => 1
                            [timezone] => +00:00
                        )

                    [end] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2014-03-31 00:00:00
                            [timezone_type] => 1
                            [timezone] => +00:00
                        )

       [start] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2014-03-01 00:00:00
                            [timezone_type] => 1
                            [timezone] => +00:00
                        )

                    [end] => DateTime Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2014-03-31 00:00:00
                            [timezone_type] => 1
                            [timezone] => +00:00
                        )
```

Create from timestamps:

```
  $begin =   DateTime::createFromFormat('U',  $filter['start'], new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
  $end =   DateTime::createFromFormat('U',  $filter['end'], new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

The first call returns correctly:

```
  (
    [days] => Array

(
    [0] => 2014-03-01
    [1] => 2014-03-02
    [2] => 2014-03-03
    [3] => 2014-03-04
    [4] => 2014-03-05
    [5] => 2014-03-06
    [6] => 2014-03-07
    [7] => 2014-03-08
    [8] => 2014-03-09
    [9] => 2014-03-10
    [10] => 2014-03-11
    [11] => 2014-03-12
    [12] => 2014-03-13
    [13] => 2014-03-14
    [14] => 2014-03-15
    [15] => 2014-03-16
    [16] => 2014-03-17
    [17] => 2014-03-18
    [18] => 2014-03-19
    [19] => 2014-03-20
    [20] => 2014-03-21
    [21] => 2014-03-22
    [22] => 2014-03-23
    [23] => 2014-03-24
    [24] => 2014-03-25
    [25] => 2014-03-26
    [26] => 2014-03-27
    [27] => 2014-03-28
    [28] => 2014-03-29
    [29] => 2014-03-30
    [30] => 2014-03-31
)

)
```

2nd call retruns the following, which lags the "2014-03-25"

```
(
    [days] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2014-03-01
            [1] => 2014-03-02
            [2] => 2014-03-03
            [3] => 2014-03-04
            [4] => 2014-03-05
            [5] => 2014-03-06
            [6] => 2014-03-07
            [7] => 2014-03-08
            [8] => 2014-03-09
            [9] => 2014-03-10
            [10] => 2014-03-11
            [11] => 2014-03-12
            [12] => 2014-03-13
            [13] => 2014-03-14
            [14] => 2014-03-15
            [15] => 2014-03-16
            [16] => 2014-03-17
            [17] => 2014-03-18
            [18] => 2014-03-19
            [19] => 2014-03-20
            [20] => 2014-03-21
            [21] => 2014-03-22
            [22] => 2014-03-23
            [23] => 2014-03-24
            [24] => 2014-03-26
            [25] => 2014-03-27
            [26] => 2014-03-28
            [27] => 2014-03-29
            [28] => 2014-03-30
            [29] => 2014-03-31
        )

)
```

I first thought of sideeffects. Am I missing one ?

In the php bugtracker is nothing concrete to my problem, but some other reports about strange behavior of DatePeriod. On the server runs a quite old php 5.3.10.

Before reproducing the bug with a newer version of php, I tried to reproduce it outside of Codeigniter. Outside it is working in various constellations. See: http://pastebin.com/FgPTSMEz

So I thought of possibly heavy memory usage in the codeigniter environment, which might cause an error. But the memory usage inside of codeigniter is only 4-5 MB. Which I reproduced in the standalone test file with reading a text file of 5 MB.

At the moment I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: `2014-03-25` is missing in your first output as well (unless that was a copy&paste mistake).

Comment: I'd be willing to bet this is DST related. Clocks changed in the UK on the 27th.

Comment: @CBroe yes c&p mistake

Comment: @Jim might be possible but since it is working outside of codeigniter, do you think there might be a setting of CI causing this ?

Comment: How are you creating the `$start` and `$end` DateTime objects you are passing into this method? If no timezone is specified while creating those (explicit or implicit) – is the current timezone setting the same when inside CI and outside?

Comment: They are created from timestamp, i edited my post to show the complete creation. My outstide testsetup: http://pastebin.com/FgPTSMEz

Comment: In another case really the clock change was the problem.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444712/php-dateinterval-missing-a-period but since the outside CI is completly the same regarding the timezones, i don't get it

Comment: Another idea : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62561

Comment: yes thats it preparing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason its PHP Bug #62561 fixed with 5.4

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62561

In a detailed debug echo you will see:

Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-01 00:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-02 01:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-03 02:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-04 03:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-05 04:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-06 05:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-07 06:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-08 07:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-09 08:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-10 09:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-11 10:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-12 11:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-13 12:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-14 13:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-15 14:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-16 15:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-17 16:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-18 17:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-19 18:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-20 19:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-21 20:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-22 21:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-23 22:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-24 23:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-26 00:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-27 01:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-28 02:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-29 03:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-30 04:00:00
Access_Model.php>getDaysInRange(1067) - Single Day in Daterange
2014-03-31 05:00:00

Quickfix / Workaround:

Since the bug is derived by creating a DateTime from timestamp with other Timezone than local timezone I wrote following quickfix

```
/**
 * Returns Days within a period of time defined by two DateTime objects
 *
 *
 * @param $start DateTime
 * @param $end DateTime
 * @param $points
 *
 * $return['days'][x]
 */
public function getDaysInRange(DateTime $start,DateTime $end){

    // Creation Workaround for Bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62561
    $startC= new DateTime($start->format('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('UTC')) ;
    $startC->setTime(0,0,0);
    $endC = new DateTime($end->format('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('UTC')) ;
    $endC->setTime(0,0,0);


    $this->debug($startC,"Get Days in Range Start");
    $this->debug($endC,"Get Days in Range End");

    $return = array('days' => array());


    // Workaround because last day of period is not in Iterator
    $endC->modify('+1 day');

while($startC < $endC) {
            $this->debug($startC->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"),"Single Day in Daterange Modify");
    $return['days'][] = $startC->format('Y-m-d');
    $startC->modify('+1 day');
}

    $this->debug($return,"Return of getDays in Range");
    return $return;
}
```